# I need to put netlogo turtles into a row

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo I need to put an agent set of turtles in a row on a given row of patches

What I came up with was

```
 (foreach sort-by [ [ t1 t2 ] -> [skill] of t1 > [skill] of t2 ] row-turtles (range length row-turtles) [ [t c] ->
      ask t [ setxy (min list c max-pxcor) (25 - ladder-rank) ]
```

(It just stacks the remaining turtles at the end)

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably try to imitate the Simple Economy model for the simplest (no pun intended) solution to your problem: just make each turtle's `xcor` as their skill. It'd be less precise, but also a much better code when you read it later:

```
to go
  ...
  ask turtles [ set xcor skill ]
  tick
end
```

Of course, you may need to normalize the scale of the skill variable to match the `min-pxcor` and `max-pxcor` of the world or change the world's dimensions. The Simple Economy model does the latter. Instead of the standard 33x33 grid with the point (0,0) at the center, it uses a 500x80 grid with the point (0,0) at the bottom left. However, normalizing your variable should be fairly trivial if you prefer not to change the world dimensions and have the turtle with the lowest skill always be at the left edge.

You can also add a bit of jitter to make sure turtles don't overlap:

```
ask turtles [ 
  set xcor skill + random-float 1 - random-float 1 
]
```

Here is the link for the Simple Economy model itself:

http://www.netlogoweb.org/launch#http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/models/IABM%20Textbook/chapter%202/Simple%20Economy.nlogo

---

An alternative approach:

If you want a nice continuous line with equal distance between turtles, you can also create a simple `foreach` loop with the `sort-on` primitive:

```
to go
  ...
  let x min-pxcor
  foreach (sort-on [skill] turtles) [ t -> 
    ask t [
      set xcor x
      set x (x + 1)
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
`
```